# Get text from text area box, and put it into a div

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Edit it</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/base/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/base/library_live.js"></script>


<style>
canvas{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<textarea id="123"> </textarea>


<script>
$("#123").keyup(function(){
   $("#user-code").html($(this).val());
   $("#user-code").text($(this).val()); // If you want html code to be escaped
});
</script>
<div id="user-code" style="display:none;">



</div>

<canvas 
width="400"
height="500"
class="codehs-editor-canvas"></canvas>

<script>
var g = new CodeHSGraphics({
    canvas: $('.codehs-editor-canvas')
});
// run test # here.
g.runCode($("#user-code").text());

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Okay so I want users to type into the text area then the code to be displayed in div user-code. Thank you :) I have tried many things but I am unable to get it to work thank you!
*Updated*
From suggestions yet still is not working
I should also point out that the div will be displaying an application or some form, using custom libraries. When I put the code in the text area it still does not show the code on the canvas.

Another way is possibly save the text area as a text doc, then use that text doc as the div id, after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzx36/3/)**

In order for the text to appear in the div tag. You should either remove the `style="display:none"` and use this jquery code:

```
$("#123").keyup(function(){
   $("#user-code").html($(this).val());
   // $("#user-code").text($(this).val()); // If you want html code to be escaped
});
```

Or this jquery will handle the hiding and displaying for you:

```
$("#123").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
       $('#user-code').css('display','none');
    }else{
       $('#user-code').css('display','block');
    }
   $("#user-code").html($(this).val());
   // $("#user-code").text($(this).val()); // If you want html code to be escaped
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it! :) Good answer!

Comment: @Amir shouldn't you first display block to #user-code ?

Comment: yup, I am updating my answer now

Comment: The text from the div id is a custom JavaScript code, which will then display the application on a canvas. This still does not help ... sorry. It has to be a live update as well.

Comment: @reidjako can you explain more what you want. I create a jsfiddle in my answer at the top (Live demo). Check it and tell me what exactly does not work

Comment: The code is copying across, but the js script has to refresh afterwards if that makes any sense at all? As the canvas is not updating with the modification of the text? @amir Thank you tho!

Comment: @reidjako if you want the canvas to be updated while typing, you can put any code inside the `keyup` method

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#user-code").css({"display" : "block"});
$("#123").keyup(function(){
   $("#user-code").html($(this).val());
   // $("#user-code").text($(this).val()); // If you want html         code to be escaped
});
```